# Jenkins cannot resolve dependencies for global shared library

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to set-up a Jenkins pipeline with Jenkinsfile which calling methods from a self-implemented global shared library with the `@Library("name-of-library")` at the head of the Jenkinsfile.

However, the library I'm using is a groovy project which is organized by Gradle. That is, we have a `build.gradle` at the root of the whole repo of the library where dependencies are defined.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'eu.agno3.jcifs', name: 'jcifs-ng', version: '2.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.8.0-beta4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    testCompile group:'com.lesfurets', name:'jenkins-pipeline-unit', version:'1.0'
}
```

When we triggered a build based on the pipeline metioned above, we found that Jenkins might not recognized the `build.gradle` which leads to the following errors:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
file:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-pipeline/builds/4/libs/name-of-library/src/com/test/model/SMBConnection.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class jcifs.context.BaseContext
 @ line 4, column 1.
   import jcifs.context.BaseContext
   ^

file:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-pipeline/builds/4/libs/name-of-library/src/com/test/model/SMBConnection.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class jcifs.config.BaseConfiguration
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import jcifs.config.BaseConfiguration
   ^

file:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-pipeline/builds/4/libs/name-of-library/src/com/test/model/SMBConnection.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class jcifs.CIFSContext
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import jcifs.CIFSContext
   ^

3 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:958)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.recompile(GroovyClassLoader.java:761)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:718)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell$TimingLoader.loadClass(CpsGroovyShell.java:158)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:545)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:185)
Caused: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'WorkflowScript' The lookup for com.test.controller.factory.CustboxFacadeFactory caused a failed compilaton. There should not have been any compilation from this call.
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveToOuter(ResolveVisitor.java:676)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:313)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1245)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:176)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$12.call(CompilationUnit.java:663)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:320)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have tried adding those dependencies at the top of Jenkinsfile with `grape` notation.

```
@Grapes([
  @Grab(group='commons-io', name='commons-io', version='2.6'),
  @Grab(group='eu.agno3.jcifs', name='jcifs-ng', version='2.1.1'),
  @Grab(group='org.slf4j', name='slf4j-api', version='1.8.0-beta4')
])
```

However, that helps nothing.
As the library I'm using contains hundurads of groovy files, I don't think adding grape notation at the beginning of each groovy file is a good idea.

I also tried convert the `build.gradle` to `pom.xml` and place it in the root of library repo. However, it helpe nothing either.

Is there anything I can try without rewriting the pipeline steps into gradle tasks and use `sh('./gradlew task-name')` in Jenkinsfile?